# Sending Onesignal/gamethrive push by JSON network request

Tags: json, push-notification, onesignal

I am trying to send a JSON request to send a push notification using the following code but I get an error message for the network response saying "app_id not found". I am using Corona but this shouldnt matter as long as JSON format is right.

```
local json = require "json"
local function networkListener( event )

    if ( event.isError ) then
        print( "Network error!" )
    else
        print ( "RESPONSE: " .. event.response )
    end
end

        headers = {}
        headers["app_id"] = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
        headers["Authorization"] = "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
        headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"

        local params = {}

        commands_json =
             {
                ["contents"] = "English Message"
             }        

        postData = json.encode(commands_json)

        local params = {}
        params.header = headers
        params.body = postData

network.request( "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications","POST",networkListener,params)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could work it out.

```
function SendJson(url, action, in_json, callback)
  local json = require ( "json" )
  local headers = {}
  headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
  headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-US"
 headers["Authorization"] = "Basic  12121321313123" -- put your Rest API

  local params = {}
  params.headers = headers
  params.body = json.encode( in_json )

  network.request ( url, action, callback, params )
end

local function networkListener( event )
  if ( event.isError ) then
    print( "Network error!")
  else
    print ( "RESPONSE: " .. event.response )
  end
end
local jsonToSend = {["app_id"] = "aaaaaa-222-222-33-3333333333", --put yours App ID
                    ["contents"] = {["en"] = "George challenged you to beat his score!"},
                    ["included_segments"] = "All",
                    ["isAndroid"] = true,
                    ["isIos"] = true,}
                    --["include_player_ids"] = ["(RECIPIENT_PLAYER_ID_HERE)"]}


SendJson("https://gamethrive.com/api/v1/notifications", "POST", jsonToSend, networkListener)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have both Android and Apple setup on your app on the OneSignal dashboard? Platforms(isAndroid and isIos) are not required parameters when you use include_player_ids.

Also make sure you don't use the Authorization header in your production app as someone can easily disassemble your app and get the REST API key. When you use the include_player_ids field the Authorization header is not required.

See the [OneSignal create notification](http://documentation.onesignal.com/v2.0/docs/notifications-create-notification) POST call for the full documentation.

Also I recommend you switch to using "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications" as the URL in your code to save on redirects.

Comment: jkasten, the method does not work without using that authorization.

Comment: When you remove ["included_segments"] and add back in ["include_player_ids"] you get an error in the response?